# Pre-signed AWS S3 URL - Preview using Quicklook framework iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, quicklook

I need to preview the files from AWS s3 presigned URL.

Does `QuickLook` framework *(QLPreviewController)* supports remote URL? Any other familiar framework available.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, QLPreviewController only supports local file URLs.